# Background-Color not applying to relative objects, but will to absolute positioning

Tags: html, css, background, position

I have no idea how/why this is happening... But I've been re-building an interface from scratch since the old one was hacky and unreliable.

Anyway, I have divs which are acting as "buttons." The gradient background I've got assigned to them wasn't working, then I stumbled across an interesting behavior... The background DOES display if I make the position attribute absolute, rather than relative.

Here are my examples:
1) [Absolute positioning](https://jsfiddle.net/PhantomDude95/23qp2j8b/1)
2) [Relative positioning](https://jsfiddle.net/PhantomDude95/23qp2j8b/3/)

The sections in question (css wise) are here:

```
.banner > .button {
position: relative;
top: 10;
display: inline-block;
height: 85%;
min-width: 80px;
margin-top: auto;
margin-bottom: auto;
text-align: center;
vertical-align: middle;
border-radius: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
-moz-border-radius: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
-webkit-border-radius: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
-webkit-user-select: none; /* Chrome/Safari */        
-moz-user-select: none; /* Firefox */
-ms-user-select: none; /* IE10+ */

/* Rules below not implemented in browsers yet */
-o-user-select: none;
user-select: none;
}
.banner > .button > span {
    left: 30%;
}
.blueGlass {
    /* Permalink - use to edit and share this gradient: http://colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/#3b679e+0,2b88d9+50,207cca+51,7db9e8+100&0.48+0,0.58+100 */
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(59,103,158,0.48) 0%, rgba(43,136,217,0.53) 50%, rgba(32,124,202,0.53) 51%, rgba(125,185,232,0.58) 100%); /* FF3.6-15 */
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(59,103,158,0.48) 0%,rgba(43,136,217,0.53) 50%,rgba(32,124,202,0.53) 51%,rgba(125,185,232,0.58) 100%); /* Chrome10-25,Safari5.1-6 */
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom,  rgba(59,103,158,0.48) 0%,rgba(43,136,217,0.53) 50%,rgba(32,124,202,0.53) 51%,rgba(125,185,232,0.58) 100%); /* W3C, IE10+, FF16+, Chrome26+, Opera12+, Safari7+ */
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#7a3b679e', endColorstr='#947db9e8',GradientType=0 ); /* IE6-9 */
    color: white;
}
.blueGlass:hover {
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 26px 12px rgba(255,255,255,0.15);
    -moz-box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 26px 12px rgba(255,255,255,0.15);
    box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 26px 12px rgba(255,255,255,0.15);
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

Any thoughts on why this is happening, and more importantly how I can go about fixing it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First issue is,

```
.banner {
    ...
    min-height: 40px;
}
```

Simply change it to,

```
.banner {
    ...
    height: 40px;
}
```

Because if you use percentage `height` value to child elements. You have to give fix height to the parent wrapper. Otherwise it will not work as you expect.

See the example: https://jsfiddle.net/23qp2j8b/4/

---

And next issue is,

Remove the `verticalCenter` in the spans. And add these stylings to the `button > span`,

```
.banner > .button > span {
    ...
    padding: 6px 15px;
    display: block;
}
```

**Complete fix example: https://jsfiddle.net/23qp2j8b/5/**

Hope this is what you needed! ;)

Comment: Ahh, didn't know that, I'll make the change. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

The `position: absolute;` for the following class `.verticalCenter` hides the color behind the gray div, change it to folowing code,It works [here](https://jsfiddle.net/ycg83q57/)

```
.verticalCenter {
  position: relative;
  top: 60%;
}
```

Comment: @Gowtham: Changing `verticalCenter` class to `top: 60%` does not makes it middle align. It will just works for that scenario only.

Comment: Ya , but your question was Background-Color not applying to relative objects, but will to absolute positioning, so i answered for that